# How to write css for that?

Tags: html, css

I am making css like

```
   <head><style type="text/css">span.blue{color:blue;}</style>;
```

and use it html like

```
 <html>I am <span class=blue>red</span></html>;
```

Now I want to avoid that span and class word in html code, is  it possible like

```
<html>I am <blue>red</blue></html>;
```

Comment: Don't why you are using so many quotes and why you are escaping part of them. That's not HTML (besides that you are missing `body` tags). But no it is not possible. HTML has a well defined set of elements. You cannot define your own.

Comment: I know it is possible but don't how to do ?

Comment: First make your question clear. What you want to achieve? I think what you want is not possible.

Comment: I want to make customized tag.

Comment: not possible or might be possible if you create your own custom DTD, but no browser would know how to style it

Comment: Yes, it is possible. No, it isn't a good idea: It will break in some browsers and it goes against good practice. You've got a perfectly good way of doing this already; why do you need to break all the standards?

Comment: I don't know why it it down votted because I want to apply this css at many place so want to write less things so it can be maintain easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can do this if you like: http://jsbin.com/uhiyoj

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />

<style>
blue {
    color: blue  
}
</style>

</head>
<body>

    <blue>Hello World</blue>

</body>
</html>
```

## But, it's a horrible idea.

Just stick with `<span class="blue">`.

Comment: It works in all browsers except IE8 and lower. If you need this to work in those browsers, you need to use [html5shiv](http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/) and then add each of your custom elements to the internal list of elements: `abbr|article|aside|audio|canvas|datalist|details|figcaption|figure|footer|header|hgroup|mark|meter|nav|output|progress|section|subline|summary|time|video` <- add `|blue`.

Comment: Worst idea i ever saw - however, it does work in IE, FF and Chrome

Comment: Ok..Sorry, I was trying this code in microsoft explorer control but in that it does not work while it works in mozzila and chorme.

Comment: I already explained how [in a previous comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7738496/how-to-write-css-for-that/7738579#comment-9417021). If you want a really, really simple fix then use `<script>document.createElement('blue');</script>`, see: http://jsbin.com/uhiyoj/2. But, this won't work in IE when you print the page.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is custom html tags. In order to use custom html tags try this [link](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/xml/article.php/3473551/So-You-Want-A-Custom-Tag-Huh.htm)
hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Firstly your HTML is not valid and does not declare a doc type. You content has to be between `<body>` for a start.

Secondly, you might be able to get away with having a 
blue:{ color:blue} in your style and defining your blue tag
but it would make your css and your html completely invalid and 0% chance of it being cross browser compatiable.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid using class and the span tag - but cannot make up your own.

- class - use relative selectors
- span - use strong/em instead - they are there for this sort of thing

Try

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
<style type="text/css">
body div strong {color:blue;}
</style>
</head>
<body><div>
I am <strong>red</strong>ok.
</div>

</body>
</html>
```